# Android Java Play gifs only once time

Tags: java, android, xml, animated-gif

I want geese when a user double-clicks on a post a gif is played. For this I used `pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView` like so:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="303dp"

            android:src="@drawable/likepopgif"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />
```

and to get it started I just used visible and invisible when needed:

```
 holder.imgPost.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

                        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                        @Override
                        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                            Toast.makeText(visualizzaPost.this, "Liked post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            holder.gifLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.gifLike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
                        }
                    });
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

obviously, however, the invisible is asynchronous with the seconds of the animation length. I'm looking for an event / property or anything else that tells the app when the animation has played and then I can make it invisible.

if i use `app:loopCount="1"` remains immoral when the loop ends in this way:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a gif to play once you can do something like this:

```java
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="303dp"

            android:src="@drawable/likepopgif"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:loopCount="1"
            />
```

And if you want to know when the gif ends you can use `getDuration()` and check if it is the same as `getCurrentPosition()`

Comment: but I would like it to be produced every time I do a double tap, if I set the limit I will not be able to reproduce it anymore

Comment: what is getCurrentPosition?

Comment: @pophome check the javadoc https://www.javadoc.io/doc/pl.droidsonroids.gif/android-gif-drawable/1.2.4/pl/droidsonroids/gif/GifDrawable.html#setLoopCount-int-

Comment: You can remove the "loopcount" limit and hide the gif when the position `getCurrentPosition()` is equal to `getDuration()`. As soon as you want to start it again you can use the function seekTo(0) to start the gif again

Comment: how do i compare them? because the comparison would also be asynchronous i think

Comment: seekTo does not exist in the properties of this object

Comment: sorry, seekTo is in fact not in the properties. You need to use MediaPlayerControl, check the example on github https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable#using-mediaplayercontrol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233617/discussion-between-maxdaman-and-pop-home).

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.imgPost.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

                        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                        @Override
                        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                            Toast.makeText(visualizzaPost.this, "Liked post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            holder.gifLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
                      holder.gifLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.example);
                            GifDrawable gifDrawable = (GifDrawable) 
                            holder.gifLike.getDrawable();
                            gifDrawable.setLoopCount(1);

                            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
                        }
                    });
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```